# Is it true that $\frac{dU}{dt}*V = U*\frac{dV}{dt}$ where not both $U,V$ are distributions and $*$ denotes convolution?

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

A theorem in my textbook states that

> Let $U,V$ be distributions and $*$ denote a convolution. Then 
>   $$\frac{dU}{dt}*V = U*\frac{dV}{dt}$$

Does this theorem hold if only $U$ is a distribution but $V$ is a "normal function" like $\sin(t)$? Are regular functions also distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily answer to this question by taking the Fourier transform. You will get
$$
{\cal F}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt'\frac{dV}{dt}(t-t')U(t')\right]=i\omega V(\omega)U(\omega)
$$
and
$$
{\cal F}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt'\frac{dU}{dt}(t-t')V(t')\right]=i\omega U(\omega)V(\omega).
$$

Comment: I haven't studied Fourier Transforms. But now I know the answer and I will go back to your answer when I have studied them. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: But then you have only showed it for Fourier transformable distributions, i.e. for tempered distributions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. These are the cases in my everyday life.